# How to process diagonal elements in Keras backend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm writing a custom loss in Keras where y_true and y_pred are tensors with size (bs, n, n, 1). I need to process these tensors diagonal elements independently from others. So, firstly I need to extract diagonals from y_true and y_pred and perform some calculations on these diagonals and secondly, I need to replace diagonals in original tensors with zeros and process y_true and y_pred. And my final loss would be a sum of these two parts.

Is there a way of doing this by means of Keras backend?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I finally managed to solve this problem myself. Here is the required function that separates tensor from its diagonal.

```
def process_diag(tensor):
    tensor = tf.squeeze(tensor, axis=[-1])
    diag = tf.matrix_diag_part(tensor)
    zeros = tf.zeros(tf.shape(tensor)[0:-1], dtype=tf.float32)
    tensor = tf.expand_dims(tf.linalg.set_diag(tensor, zeros, name=None), -1)
    return tensor, diag
```